# Mixing memory modules

Tags: memory

We have Fujitsu RX100 S6 server.

1. Originally there was a single 1066 MHz 4GB registered DDR3 module.
2. We've bought 2x 4GB 1333 MHz registered modules.

After plugging-in the new modules overall frequency dropped to 800 MHz.
Is it a feature or a bug? Because we've thought that the overall frequency is computed as a minimum from {1066, 1333} = 1066.

Thanks very much for any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set in the BIOS the RAM Speed, I don't really know the layout of a Fujitsu Server Motherboard BIOS but you should be able to set it. Also mixing memory isn't really the best way to go about stability. If you're running a server you should consider having the same brand of memory to avoid any problems that can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The [SPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) of the new ram might have weird defaults which would require you to manually specify the settings in the BIOS.

According to this [data sheet](https://globalsp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/docs/ds-py-rx100-s6.pdf), it looks like there are 4 memory slots, and the server only supports [dual-channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-channel_architecture). That means that if you have all 3 sticks in you will be running single channel as they need to be installed in pairs for dual.